# SQL MAX date with WHERE IN Clause

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I will give 2 examples, 1st one that works, and the 2nd with what I want to do:

```
SELECT P.ProjName, D.update_date, SUM(E.pass), SUM(E.fail)
  FROM execution AS E INNER JOIN ( 
    daily AS D INNER JOIN project AS P ON D.project_ID = P.ID )
    ON E.daily_ID = D.ID
  WHERE D.project_id = 25 AND D.update_date = ( 
    SELECT MAX(update_date) FROM daily WHERE project_id = 25; )
  GROUP BY P.ProjName, D.update_date;
```

This will work for individual projects. It gives me the total of Pass and Fails for the latest day of a given project (here, 25).  I would like to grab a group of projects using an WHERE IN clause.  For example (but does not work):

```
SELECT P.ProjName, D.update_date, SUM(E.pass), SUM(E.fail)
  FROM execution AS E INNER JOIN ( 
    daily AS D INNER JOIN project AS P ON D.project_ID = P.ID )
    ON E.daily_ID = D.ID 
  WHERE D.project_id IN (25,26,28,29,30,31)
  GROUP BY P.ProjName, D.update_date
  HAVING MAX(D.update_date);
```

This will result in every date getting pulled for each of the projects. There are 3 tables involved, 'project' which is linked by 'daily', which is linked by 'execution'.  So, for every project, there is multiple daily data, and each day has multiple execution data.  I realize the HAVING MAX probably needs a comparison, but to what?  Perhaps a modified JOIN will help.

Thanks,
Keith

Comment: This is an MS Access DB using and ADODB connector (Jet 4) from Excel VBA. The first answer, solved it.  Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: One additional note. I needed to add P.ID to the SELECT and GROUP BY statements to maintain the original order.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a bit tricky trying to do this without knowing the database but try this:

```
SELECT P.ProjName, D.update_date, SUM(E.pass), SUM(E.fail)
  FROM execution AS E INNER JOIN ( 
    daily AS D INNER JOIN project AS P ON D.project_ID = P.ID )
    ON E.daily_ID = D.ID
  WHERE D.project_id IN (25,26,28,29,30,31) AND D.update_date = ( 
    SELECT MAX(update_date) FROM daily WHERE project_id = D.project_id)
  GROUP BY P.ProjName, D.update_date;
```

I really have no idea if this is close to anything you'd want.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a particular DBMS, so how about this (untested) SQL code which should for the most part be DBMS agnostic:

```
SELECT P.ProjName, 
       DesiredProjectUpdateDate.MaxUpdateDate, 
       SELECT SUM(pass) AS PassSum 
       FROM execution 
       WHERE daily_ID=D.ID,
       SELECT SUM(fail) AS FailSum 
       FROM execution 
       WHERE daily_ID=D.ID
FROM
( -- This derived table helps you get the correct records from the daily table
  SELECT D.project_ID, MAX(D.Update_date) AS MaxUpdateDate 
  FROM daily AS D
  GROUP BY D.project_ID
  WHERE D.project_ID IN (25,26,28,29,30,31)
) As DesiredProjectUpdateDate
JOIN daily AS D
  ON D.project_ID=DesiredProjectUpdateDate.project_ID AND
     D.Update_date=DesiredProjectUpdateDate.MaxUpdateDate
JOIN project AS P
  ON P.ID = DesiredProjectUpdateDate.ProjectId
```

Give that a shot and let me know if you have any further issues.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you need a select which returns the max value of update_date for each project.

Try this:

```
SELECT P.ProjName, D.update_date, SUM(E.pass), SUM(E.fail)
  FROM execution AS E INNER JOIN ( 
    daily AS D INNER JOIN project AS P ON D.project_ID = P.ID )
    ON E.daily_ID = D.ID 
  WHERE D.project_id IN (25,26,28,29,30,31)
  AND D.update_date > ALL
  (SELECT update_date FROM
   daily AS D2
   WHERE D.ID=D2.ID -- I am assuming that daily.ID is the primary key
   AND ISNULL(D.update_date, '9999 DEC 31') <> D2.update_date)
  GROUP BY P.ProjName, D.update_date;
```

I quite often write queries like this and they are faster than using the `MAX` aggregate function and work nicely.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I forgot to remove your now-redundant `HAVING MAX...` line. My bad!

Comment: Yes, but it gives me an error: "Wrong number of arguments used with function in query expression 'D.ID = D2.ID AND ISNULL(D.update_date, '9999 DEC 31') <> D2.update_date'."  Perhaps Jet doesn't like ISNULL?  I did try it without the ISNULL and it gave me every date.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't know too much about Jet/Access, but I gave you T-SQL code... Thanks for letting me know it didn't work out.

Comment: I found the answer to the ISNULL for Jet, you need to use the IIf syntax.  `AND IIf(( SELECT MAX(update_date) FROM daily " WHERE project_ID = D.project_ID ) IS NULL, 0, ( SELECT MAX(update_date) FROM daily WHERE project_ID = D.project_ID )) = IIf(D.update_date IS NULL, 0, D.update_date)"`.  I also made the joins RIGHT JOINS so that I could get all of the projects, even if they didn't have dates (non-updated projects).

Comment: That's cool. Thanks for the update which will be handy if anyone else reads this. But I guess you ended up using the other solution. :-)